# ¿Cómo pasar registros de una tabla de datos a otra automáticamente?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Tengo una tabla de datos encargada de supervisar las vistas, por la alta demanda suelo vaciar/eliminar datos, entonces consultando esos datos:

```
$use_proxy = 1;
$stmtVPN = $con->prepare("SELECT visitor_ip_remote, visitor_proxy FROM visitor_ip WHERE visitor_proxy=?");
$stmtVPN->bind_param("i",$use_proxy);
$stmtVPN->execute();
$stmtVPN->store_result();

$stmtVPN->bind_result($ip_remote, $proxy);
//$stmtVPN->fetch();
$datas = '';
$data = '';
while ($stmtVPN->fetch()) {
    $datas .= $ip_remote;
    $data .= $proxy;
}
$stmtVPN->close();
```

¿Cómo puedo pasar esos registros de las `IP` que usan `proxy` a otra tabla de datos? La nueva tabla de datos va almacenar dichas `ip` que utilizan proxy, donde esa `ip` será bloqueada temporalmente.

En esta nueva tabla de datos a la cual he llamado `black_list` no deben ir registros repitos, es decir no deseo obtener la misma `ip` registrada varias veces, porque en esta nueva tabla se registran datos únicos dados al trafico anterior del análisis:

Para ello creo la siguiente consulta, para evitar registros duplicados:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT visitor_ip_remote FROM visitor_ip WHERE visitor_ip_remote=?");
$stmt->bind_param("s",$datas);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($datasBD);
$stmt->fetch();
$stmt->close();

if(strtolower($datasBD) == strtolower($datas)){
    //echo "";
    exit;
}
```

Y, finalmente teniendo el siguiente código:

```
<?php
$use_proxy = 1;
$stmtVPN = $con->prepare("SELECT visitor_ip_remote, visitor_proxy FROM visitor_ip WHERE visitor_proxy=?");
$stmtVPN->bind_param("i",$use_proxy);
$stmtVPN->execute();
$stmtVPN->store_result();

$stmtVPN->bind_result($ip_remote, $proxy);
//$stmtVPN->fetch();
$datas = '';
$data = '';
while ($stmtVPN->fetch()) {
    $datas .= $ip_remote;
    $data .= $proxy;
}
$stmtVPN->close();

$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT visitor_ip_remote FROM visitor_ip WHERE visitor_ip_remote=?");
$stmt->bind_param("s",$datas);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($datasBD);
$stmt->fetch();
$stmt->close();

if(strtolower($datasBD) == strtolower($datas)){
    //echo "";
    exit;
}


$stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO black_list (ip_blocked, proxy) VALUES (?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("ss",$datas,$data);
$stmt->execute();
```

El problema es que solo me registra un dato y, todos los datos unidos en un solo registro como se muestra en la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces ¿Cómo puedo registrar estos datos correctamente?

> Nota: En la tabla `visitor_ip` existen más de mil registros.

Comment: Yo crearía un trigger, con eso la BD se ocuparía de mover los datos por su cuenta.

Comment: @Alfabravo Primera vez que escucho eso? de que se trata?

Comment: Para MySQL 8, la documentación oficial está [aquí](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html)

Comment: Igual lo que hace mysql es correcto... vos estas pasando un solo valor en cada variable del insert. Un insert, inserta un solo dato en la tabla...

Comment: @gbianchi pero esa nos es mi idea, porque como dije necesito pasar todos esos datos a una nueva tabla automáticamente, entonces toca hacer la consulta dentro del bucle `while`

Comment: Estudia como funciona la clausula insert en mysql. Se inserta un registro por vez...